# Threejs orbit control not work correctly on touch devices

Tags: mobile, three.js, 3d, touch

I have a threejs scene with a object loaded and a camera that must rotate around it as the user drags on the screen.
This works well in a computer, but on touch devices no.
If it's turned without zooming (pinch), it works well,
if it's zoomed and then turned it does not work well.
The object as it turns become enlarged and reduced,
i don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Could you provide a live code example, showing the problem?

Comment: Yes sorry, this is the website demo: http://atktest.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
init();
animate();

function init() {

    w_container = $obj3D.width();
    h_container = $obj3D.height();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, w_container / h_container, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.z = zoom_value;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, $obj3D[0]);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.08;
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.03;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.5;
    controls.minDistance = 30;  
    controls.maxDistance = 230;
    controls.update();

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.4);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x5a5a5a, .7);
    pointLight.power = .6;
    pointLight.position.set(50, 50, 50);
    camera.add(pointLight);

    scene.add(camera);

    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());

    new THREE.MTLLoader()
            .setPath('models/packagin/')
            .setMaterialOptions({side: THREE.DoubleSide})
            .load('oggetto.mtl', function (materials) {

                materials.preload();

                new THREE.OBJLoader()
                        .setMaterials(materials)
                        .setPath('models/packagin/')
                        .load('oggetto.obj', function (object) {

                            object.traverse(function (child) {

                                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                                }
                            });

                            object.position.y = -28;

                            OBJ = object;

                            scene.add(object);

                        }, onProgress, onError);

            });

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(w_container, h_container);
    $obj3D[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener('resize', canvasResize, false);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
}
```

}